# React Router Webpack async chunk loading

Tags: webpack, react-router

I have a Route Component which I want to load async with webpack:

```
<Route path="dashboard" getComponent={(location, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], (require) => {
    cb(null, require('./Containers/Dashboard'));
  });
}}>
```

This is a lot of boilerplate if you have a lot of others routes that need async chunk loading. So I thought, let's refactor this into a helper method:

```
const loadContainerAsync = route => (location, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], (require) => {
    cb(null, require('../Containers/' + route));
 });
};

// much 'nicer syntax'
<Route path="dashboard" getComponent={loadContainerAsync('Dashboard')} />
```

Apparently when I look at the network tab in the firefox-devtools, the behavior of the loadContainerAsync function doesn't function correctly. Any idea what could be wrong with my function loadContainerAsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try using the [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader).

```
const loadContainerAsync = bundle => (location, cb) => {
  bundle(component => {
    cb(null, component);
  });
};

// 'not so nice syntax', but better than first option :)
<Route path="dashboard" getComponent={loadContainerAsync(require('bundle?lazy!../containers/Dashboard'))} />
```

Don't forget to `$ npm install bundle-loader --save-dev`.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem for now. Syntax is less atrocious than the require.ensure callback hell ;)

Comment: this doesn't work for isomorphic apps though.  the require('bundle?lazy!') blows up... :(

Comment: any thoughts on why webpack wont even generate chunks based on require.ensure statements.

Comment: Take a look here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#context-module. Webpack will generate chunks on require.ensure, but if it's a dynamic require, all files that can match that require will end up in the same chunk

Answer (score 0):

getComponent expects a function, you could try:

```
const loadContainerAsync = route => (location, cb) => {
  return (location, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('../Containers/' + route));
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the fact you already wrapped it in a method (damn you ES6 :)

Comment: Np :) Gotta love ES6 ;p